# C#: Method not found exception (Setter missing)

Tags: c#, exception

I'm facing really strange error while debugging my program. I have a data contract where I added new properties but one of them cause the following exception:

`Method not found: 'Void Measurement.set_ContactId(Int32)'.`

The data contract looks following:

```
[DataContract]
public class Measurement
{
    [DataMember]
    public int FactId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
.....
```

I don't really understand what can be a problem since, as I said, I added some other properties but there was no problem with them.

UPD: The exception is happening on the service side when I try to assign a value to `ContactId`:

```
foreach (Measurement m in result.Where(m => m.FactId == factId)){
    m.ContactId = contactId;
  .....
```

Comment: Do you have a `set_ContactId(Int32)` method in your `Measurement` class?

Comment: Why would I need that there? There is already a setter for `ContactId` declared. Plus, if I try to add it, I get an error: `Method with the same signature is already declared.`

Comment: Do a clean rebuild and update your service references

Comment: @Adil, did you read my question? I do in fact use `public int FactId`...

Comment: He suggested to change from property to variable - just remove `{get;set;}`

Comment: @Adil, @Reniuz, why would that cause such exception just for that property? I don't get it. If `{get;set;}` causes exception for `ContactId`, then I'd guess it should cause the same problem for other properties.

Comment: I tried to remove getter and setter. Now I got `Field not found: 'Measurement.ContactId'.` Very strange...

Comment: Because properties are translated to get_ set_ methods. Is this original code(copy pasted) from your source? You doing something wrong.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem was with some older version of the DLL which was stored in .NET's cache. I made a search on the whole disk for the DLL and deleted all found files (some were in use by the .NET so I had to use Unlocker). After rebuilding the project it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

If this Measurement class is part of your WCF service, then you have it on both side of your service (client side and server side). Do both side have the same version (where ContactId has a setter)?

Comment: Yes, both client and the server sides have the same version of `Measurement`. Plus, the exception is happening on the server side when I try to assign a value to `ContactId`

Comment: What is your WCF protocol? TCP, soap...?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the method cones from a Nuget package, update or reinstall the package